# Mongoose subdocument virtual populate breaks subsequent calls

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

After I call populate on a subdocument, any subsequent populate calls on that subdocument fail.

I have these schemas defined:

```
const MessageSchema = new Schema({
  accountId: {type: ObjectId},
  authorId: {type: ObjectId},
  conversationId: {type: ObjectId},
  body: {type: Object},
  createdAt: {type: Date},
}, {
  toObject: {
    virtuals: true,
  },
});

MessageSchema.virtual('author', {
  ref: 'User',
  localField: 'authorId',
  foreignField: '_id',
  justOne: true,
});

module.exports.Message = mongoose.model('Message', MessageSchema);

const Conversation = new Schema({
  accountId: {type: String},
  authorId: {type: ObjectId},
  createdAt: {type: Date},
  isArchived: {type: Boolean},
  lastMessage: MessageSchema,
  participants: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'}],
}, {
  toObject: {
    virtuals: true,
  },
});

Conversation.virtual('account', {
  ref: 'Account',
  localField: 'accountId',
  foreignField: '_id',
  justOne: true,
});

module.exports.Conversation = mongoose.model('Conversation', Conversation);
```

I have a route which runs this:

```
  const messages = await MessageModel.find({
    conversationId: ObjectId(req.params.conversationId),
  })
  .populate('author')
  .sort('+createdAt')
  .skip(skip)
  .limit(limit);
```

author is returned as to be expected, however, if I run the following, any subsequent calls to the above do not load in the author.

```
  const conversation = await ConversationModel.findOne({
    _id: ObjectId(req.params.conversationId),
  })
  .populate('participants')
  .populate('lastMessage.author')
  .populate('account')
  .exec();
```

It's a really bizarre one and I cannot figure out why it is happening. If I remove `.populate('lastMessage.author')` the problem goes away, but I need to populate it.

Comment: It appears to be an issue with the Subdocument. If I duplicate the MessageSchema just for use by the ConversationSchema, I no longer have the problem.